# Moderators should give time & scope of discussion before deleting a post for active users

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers, suggestions

This discussion is neither intended for the few novice users who post low quality answers nor for actually "not an answer" kind of posts. Rather it's intended for the situations, where moderators end up deleting a post from an active user who is well versed about site rules.

**Suggestion: For the posts which are not straight forward candidate for deletion/closure, the moderators may comment under the post & give some time for improvement & discussion. Then it should be followed by the deletion/closing.**

Advantages:

- If moderator discusses the probable problem under the post itself,
  then it remains local. It doesn't go public at all if such comments
  are deleted later once the issue is resolved.
- When the user has to come to general chatroom or ask a Q in meta
  like this, then the issue becomes public. The user will get away
  easily, but it will raise eyebrows against moderator, even though
  Mod might be right

---

### Why this Q?

There might be multiple instances, however I will describe about my answer being deleted:
[What does Hindu scripture say about class hierarchy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11240/1049)

[image]

(1) Mod wanted to know about "compatibility of Hinduism and communism" as per comment, but the OP doesn't ask that part anywhere. OP has bit generalized it to "the religion" in very last statement. Nevertheless assuming that "religion = Hinduism" (which is actually not true), I have answered both the things as seen in my last paragraph above.

(2) Now read the first line of OP's (apparently wrong) understanding about "caste system in scriptures". That's also answered here:

[image]

(3) Next, OP wants to know whether the "caste system" can be followed in classless society. Though he/she doesn't want to know about "castes", but welcomes contexts. That part is also answered:

[image]

(4) Lastly the title of the Q. This is where the complete context is needed, because OP is actually pointing towards "division system", misinterpreting as "caste system". That part is also answered with proper analogies.

[image]

Objectively, I don't feel anything which was not answered. Scriptures were also backed up. To reduce the length, other 2 answers were linked inside that answer.

---

Upon discussing this with the moderator in their [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28757898#28757898), I failed to convince. Ofcourse many may agree or disagree with me. **But this is definitely a case which is not worthy of "straight away delete".**

<sub>**Another request**: Kindly don't bring personal disliking for something as a decision maker. e.g., there are few foreigner's questions (including this) who felt that "Hinduism" promotes "caste-ism". It's our moral responsibility to clarify to them, that sane Hindus never believed in such rotten system either. Some people may really like "caste-system", which is not wrong. But this should not be a basis of deleting or closing anything. One can always down vote.</sub>

Comment: Here's the rule of thumb I generally follow: if a post answers the question but it has quality issues, like it doesn't cite sources or it's a pure copy-paste answer, then I give the user the opportunity to fix those issues before deleting it. (Unless the answer is super-short, in which case we have the less drastic option of converting to a comment.) But if an answer does not actually answer the question asked, then I delete it first and give the user the opportunity to make the post answer the question.

Comment: In this case, apart from a brief remark at he end the bulk of your answer did not actually answer the question.  That's why I deleted it.  But I'm happy to undelete if you edit your post to make it an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, to make you happy, I can edit it for formality & then you may undelete the answer. But the actual problem is: every time I have to remember your preferences, rather than thinking about the natural answer coming to my mind. There is no definition in any SE that "in X proportion, we should write". For Mods@here, only 2 things to be checked: If the Q is covered & scriptures are cited. In above screenshots, both criteria are satisfied. My answer devotes to all the sub Qs & misinterpretations the OP had. If anyone **objectively** points problem in my answer, it will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that you only devote a couple sentences to actually answering the question asked.  If you devoted the bulk of your answer to answering the actual question, then it would be more acceptable.

Comment: I read a comment by @Mr.Alien earlier that, since our site is in Beta, the moderators have been requested (or have taken it upon themselves) to increase site quality by deleting as and when they feel necessary. If our site ever makes it out of beta, I would say that this would no longer be the case. The problem with our site is that there are not enough active users as of yet, who will vote to reopen or vote to close answers. However these are general comments regarding your question. This is not applicable to your specific example. I am always for giving more time, especially to active users.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "    
The problem is that you only devote a couple sentences to actually answering the question asked." Not everyone likes to read or write pages and pages when a succinct answer shall suffice. Your personal standards in this regard are not accurate.

Comment: Visit [Official policy for deleting answers that don't cite sources](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/803/277).

Comment: @Pandya, congratulations for becoming a Mod. Post linked seems a good initiative. I have a list of wrongful deleted answers. One from [moonstar](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12306/1049) is now undeleted (though with some irrelevant scriptures). Since you commented here, may be you can put an answer to this post that, why [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11246/1049), [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5453/1049) & [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16359/1049) answers are still deleted (**as is**), Even when they attempt to answer the Qn with scripture. Thanks!