# Answer wrongly deleted - 2 [resolved]

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations, answers, moderators

Here is the post:
[What does Hindu scripture say about class hierarchy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11240/1049).

There are 2 requirements for answer to be valid:

1. Attempt to answer (overall SE)
2. Cite sources (Hinduism SE)

My answer satisfies both. It answers all Qn-s 1 by 1 with scriptures. Under which written policy is it deleted?

<sub>Note: This post is also discussed as preface in This meta post: [Moderators should give time & scope of discussion before deleting a post for active users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/513/1049).  But they are not duplicates.</sub>

Comment: Please add your issues in a single post instead of posting series of questions on metal

Comment: Milind, can u post one question per day? Now its too many things to read  So might miss out on something:D

Comment: @Rickross, OK I discussed already in other post, that why I posted multiple Qn-s. BTW, I feel that this answer is eligible for the straight forward undelete as well. In this post, I have answered all the separate Qn-s by the OP 1 by 1 with scriptures. The reason given for the deletion was that, the "amount" of answering to main Qn is less than the other part of answer -- ([see here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/513/moderators-should-give-time-scope-of-discussion-before-deleting-a-post-for-act#comment1692_513)). But that is highly subjective, as we don't count lines.

Comment: @iammilind We undeleted as question is unclear. It's not clear what OP's main question is. It seems he is asking about Caste System but again it looks he is not asking about caste system."This question asks is it necessary," but also OP says " I'm not asking about the why of the caste system,". Since your answer mentions about Caste system, it is undeleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see **no justification** for deleting this answer. Must be undeleted, because the post attempts to answer the Qn-s along with the scriptures.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i have understood OP is basically asking the following question:

**Should the caste systems  be followed ?** ( i think  reference here is to the 4 varnas ? )

In his own words,

> This question asks **is it necessary, and does the religion work
>   with Communism.**

Well, the caste systems are prescribed in scriptures to be followed only what else? Hence,  for me not that  great a question.

And, if i was answering then i would have simply mentioned YES. If we go by scriptures we can't say that the caste systems mustn't be followed. Whether its follow able now or not is not my concern.

Now, what @iammilind tried to do in his answer is to point out the difference between may be *jati* and *varna*. Which is a good thing to do specially if you are explaining things to someone who's alien to Hindu concepts.

In any case,  milind's answer is this:

> **Whether to follow "caste system" or to continue "division system" is upto the society.** The post independence India was leaned more
>   towards Russian style "Communism" ("Socialism" to be precise) and the
>   "caste system" co-existed with it. In recent times, it's diminishing
>   largely.
>
> **"Division system" is not something follow-able, they exist anyhow.**

Well, again that's his answer. So irrespective of whether its good or bad, right or wrong how  can it be deleted? Because, supposedly, only "not an answer" can be deleted.

And he has cited some verses from Bhagavad Gita too.

**IMO this answer also should be undeleted.**

Answer (score 2):

I found [the question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11240/2995) itself confusing so it's the question that should be deleted (or edited to clarify) not your answer.

OP clarifies in the comment as:

> My question is clearly about whether Hinduism and the social aspects of Marxism could co-exist.

That to me is a hypothetical question a.k.a 'not a real question' or 'unclear what you're asking.'

Also, in the question OP asks:

> Must these systems be followed or ...

That will lead to opinion-based answers.

I've voted to close [the question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11240/2995).

Comment: I won't vote here. You should start a new meta post or convert this answer to a comment, because either it's a suggestion on the Qn or the current action you took. This meta post should be limited to answer deletion. Else we will be deviated. :-)

Comment: 'the question should be deleted not your answer' - so it does address your question a bit.